# Cooldown for users for many servers discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing discord bot on python (discord.py). This bot for many servers and I want to make cooldown system. This looks like this:
User uses command on the first server and if he uses it again, bot will tell user that command on cooldown, but if user will go to the second server, command will work without cooldown that is on the first server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)

First number is how many times someone can run the command without triggering the cooldown.

Second one is how long the cooldown is in seconds.
BucketType tells the bot its per user, there are different bucket types, for example for roles, server and so on.

Refer to the dpy docs.

As far as I know bucket type user is server dependent. So it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

A simple command cooldown will do it!

```py
@commands.cooldown(1, 20, commands.BucketType.user)
```

**This does work, but be carful. Restarting your bot removes the cooldown.**